# Why do I get an error 22300 when adding a new linked service on Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

I am new to Azure. I am currently exploring Azure Synapse. I have a local SQL Server Express database on my laptop and I wanted to connect it as a data source on my Azure Synapse. I selected SQL Server:

[image]

[image]

Now when I tested the connection I get the following error:

The problem is I get a `22300` error:

```
Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'DESKTOP-xxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS', Database: 'David', User: 'Bidi'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified), SqlErrorNumber=-1,Class=20,State=0,
Activity ID: eafe37de-fabf-43d6-914f-25e8685bb149.
```

I even tried enabling the port in the SQL configuration manager:

[image]

And I made a firewall rule to allow the port:

[image]

Unfortunately I still can't get the linked service on Synapse to connect to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You *do* understand how IP works, right? And NAT? And why `DESKTOP-xxxxxx` is not an internet-resolvable nor routable machine name?

Comment: Azure isn't in your domain; it's not going to be able to connect to it. You're treating Azure like it's a Network service, not a cloud service.

Comment: I put xx just to mask the name. Any ideas on why I am getting the error?.

Comment: @Larnu What's worse: directly exposing a localhost SQL Server instance to the public Internet, or the fact someone is using Azure Synapse? :3

Comment: So just to summarize, it is impossible to connect to local sql db via azure?

Comment: @DavidCopperfield Yes - by analogy, it's like telling someone your address is "Chair" (because that's presumably where you're currently sitting) but without qualifying what house, address, floor, city, or even country that chair is located in...

Comment: @DavidCopperfield Yes, it's possible to connect Azure Synapse to on-prem/local, _but not like that_: see here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/integration-with-on-premises-data-sources-in-azure-synapse-analytics/

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go. One question I do have is why does Azure Synapse have 'SQL Server' as an option?

Comment: Because it is a real option, supported by the self hosted runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install the [Self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#self-hosted-integration-runtime) in your on-premises network, for example on the machine running SQL server:

> A self-hosted IR is capable of:
>
> Running copy activity between a cloud data stores and a data store in private network.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#setting-up-a-self-hosted-integration-runtime) on how to install and configure the runtime .

Comment: If I do that will the connection between Azure and my local SQL db work?

Comment: Yes, it is a vital component since it handles the communication between azure and the on-premises server. You certainly do not want to open tour SQL server to the whole world.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a go. In a sense it's similar to Power BI gateway I guess. As Power BI Gateway allows Power BI Service to connect to a local SQL db.

Comment: Correct. It makes it possible to connect to on-premises data sources without compromising security.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful to know. Out of curiosity, did I upload compromising data in my question above?.

Comment: Not really AFAIK